# Remover classes recursivamente

Tags: html, jquery

#### Cenário teste

Tenho um menu, com sub-itens, em que cada sub-item é um link:

```
<ul id="MenuTabs" class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="TabInfo" class="nav-link text-danger active"href="#" onclick="info()"><i class="fas fa-info"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="Tab1" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tab 1</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a id="tab1opc1" class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="t1o1()">Opção 1 Tab 1</a>
            <a id="tab1opc2" class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="t1o2()">Opção 2 Tab 1</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="Tab2" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tab 2</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a id="tab2opc1" class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="t2o1()">Opção 1 Tab 2</a>
            <a id="tab2opc2" class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="t2o2()">Opção 2 Tab 2</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a id="Tab3" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-dark" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Tab 3</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a id="tab3opc1" class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="t3o1()">Opção 1 Tab 3</a>
            <a id="tab3opc2" class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="t3o2()">Opção 2 Tab 3</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

#### Funcionamento

Cada sub-item, é um link com uma ação *JQuery*, e essa ação ao ser disparada deve adicionar a classe `active` na aba raiz (até aqui sem problema).

O problema, é saber de qual a "aba anterior" para remover a classe `active`.

---

#### Dúvidas

- Gostaria de saber, é se existe uma forma no *JQuery* que remova de forma recursiva, qualquer elemento que tenha a classe `active`, nesse caso.

Algo do tipo `$('#MenuTabs').removeClass('active')`, mas que pegue todos elementos dentro do elemento `id="MenuTabs"`.

Comment: Não seria apenas `$('#MenuTabs .active').removeClass('active')`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Exatamente isso professor! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você fazer:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
```

Isso removerá a classe `active` **de qualquer elemento** que possuí-la.

Caso queira limitar a árvore de busca para evitar conflitos com o restante da página, você pode utilizar do seletor CSS que define o elemento *root*: `root .active`, assim buscará apenas elementos com a classe `.active` dentro de `root`. Considerando o elemento pai como `#MenuTabs`, bastaria fazer:

```
$('#MenuTabs .active').removeClass('active')
```